# Is formatting "I am" to "I'm" really a necessary revision to an existing post?

Tags: discussion, edits, specific-edit

I have [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34918239/typeerror-undefined-ins-not-a-function-simple-chat-application) question on Stackoverflow from almost 5 years back. A [recent revision](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/34918239/revisions) was done on this question by a user with 2k+ reputation where the only changes were changing the words "I am" to "I'm" and actually even improperly formatting a code by adding an extra space to it: `socket.set()` to `socket.set()` . I did not get an option to approve or reject this revision. This question is not a complaint, but I am confused, why would someone do this? Is there reputation points to be gained by making revisions to posts?

Answer (score 12):

Yes, this seems like a uselessly trivial edit. It is clear that their primary motivation was to add inline code formatting to the `socket.set()` function call, but that is not necessary, nor does it materially improve the readability of the question. Converting from the long form to a contraction is also not considered to be an improvement.

However, the user who made that edit does not gain any reputation for doing so. Users with [full editing privileges](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/edit) stand to gain nothing but an improved site.

In an isolated case, this probably isn't worth worrying about. If the edit bothers you, you can roll it back. If you have concerns that a particular user is making a large number of trivial edits, then you should raise a custom moderator flag on one of the posts they edited and cite evidence of the pattern of abuse.

Comment: *"In isolated case, this probably isn't worth worrying about."*, you should see their revision history then :rolls_eyes:

Comment: Not sure about "stand to gain nothing".. they gain the Carnaval hat! :)

Comment: @Nick Read on: the answer provides a solution for precisely that problem!

Comment: @CodyGray Selective reading, apologies :p

Comment: Sorry, I didn't think this one was long enough for a TL;DR, @Nick. ;-p

Comment: it is ok to correct spelling anbd typosm, so i'm uis a valid edit

Comment: Yes, that is OK. This edit did neither of those things, @nbk.

Comment: Well, the user does not get reputation, but he might get a gold badge for editing more than 500 posts. Maybe that's the target in those cases...